# Can TFS 2010 build controllers & build agents run on Server 2012?

Tags: tfsbuild, windows-server-2012

Our TFS 2010 Build Controller and Build Agents (regrettably) live on our Dev app server, which we're planning to upgrade from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012.  We don't have immediate plans to upgrade to TFS 2012, however.  Is Windows Server 2012 a supported OS for the TFS Build 2010 components?  I thought that it would be easy to find the answer, but all of the links I've found thus far talk about running TFS Build 2010 components against TFS 2012, which is not our scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2010 is not supported with Windows Server 2012.  You can find the official list of OS compatibility here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/dd578592(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Do you know for sure that Server 2012 is not supported?  Given that the compat page was published in the 2010 timeframe, I wouldn't expect it to mention future OS releases, even if it was compatible.

Comment: They do keep those pages up-to-date.  Do you mean does it work, or is it supported.  It definitely isn't supported, but not sure if it's possible to make it work; but I doubt it.